# Symfony - Problemas na instalação em Windows 8

Tags: php, symfony-2, windows-8

Estou tentando instalar o Symfony no Windows 8, mas recebo a mensagem do Windows que "Este aplicativo não pode ser executado em seu PC". 
Isso ocorre quando, através do CLI, tento o comando `symfony generate:project symfony_project`dentro do caminho **C:\wamp\www\symfony_project**

A ideia é instalar no WAMP, e estou seguindo os tutoriais dos links:

- https://anandshahil11.wordpress.com/symfony-php-framwework-installation-on-windows-wamp/
- http://www.about-dev.com/symfony/35-how-to-install-symfony-in-a-wamp-server-project-and-make-it-work (neste caso, tentei também usar o Composer, mas a mensagem é a mesma).

Seria um problema de versão? Ou existe outra maneira de instalar?

Comment: Se esse erro ocorre é porque você não definiu o symfony na variavel de ambiente PATH. Outra coisa, na verdade você não precisa criar a pasta `symfony_project`, ao executar o generate ele já faz isso, se você fizer isto dentro da pasta vai ficar assim:  `C:\wamp\www\symfony_project\symfony_project`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento realmente não defini o Symfony na variáve de ambiente PATH (no tutorial fala apenas sobre as variáveis ;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin - no meu caso). Como ficaria a variável de ambiente para o Symfony?